# What does "Trinidadian rapper" mean?

Tags: meaning

I read an article about Nicki Minaj's song, [Roman's Revenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman%27s_Revenge).

It said that

> "Roman's Revenge" is a song by **Trinidadian rapper** Nicki Minaj, featuring American rapper Eminem, from Minaj's debut studio album Pink Friday.

In the page of [Nicki Minaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicki_Minaj) itsefl also said

> Onika Tanya Maraj (born December 8, 1982), professionally known by her stage name Nicki Minaj, is a **Trinidadian-born American rapper**, singer and songwriter.

What the meaning Trinidadian is? Is it name of place or what?

Answer (score 4):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinidad_and_Tobago

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinidadians

**Trinidadians** are simply people who live on the island of Trinidad (in your case, Nicki Minaj was born there). I won't bite here: simply because if you don't pay too much attention in geography you probably don't know that this small place exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this answer here:

Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinidadian_and_Tobagonian_Americans

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Link-only answers are discouraged; you should try to explain to the questioner what the answer is.